# Flutter how can I know when the timer stopped?

Tags: flutter, timer

When app go to background, the timer would stop about 30 seconds later(in iOS).

Can I listen whether the timer stopped or not?

Note: I want to know **when** the timer stopped.

Comment: callback function!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use _timer.isActive

> Returns whether the timer is still active.

> A non-periodic timer is active if the callback has not been executed, and the timer has not been canceled.

> A periodic timer is active if it has not been canceled.

**EDIT**

if you wish to make a callback after 30 seconds, you can do

```
Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 30), (){
 //do something here
});
```

Comment: I want to know **when** the timer stopped.